# Searching a set of records in Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have written code to search for the First name and last name and display those particular records if available and perform actions like update and delete on those records , I have written the following code to search , please tell me what is the correct approach to build a search controller .I am getting the following error :

```
Message: Method "select" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()
```

The code I have written in the controller is :

```
public function searchAction($params)
{
    $query = $this->select()
                 ->from(
                array('EMPLOYEES'),
                array('FIRST_NAME','LAST_NAME','SALARY','HIREDATE')
                );
$query = $this->_makeParams($query,$params);
return $this->fetchAll($query);
}

private function _makeParams($query, $params)
{
    $firstname = isset($params['firstname']) ? trim($params['firstname']) : '';
    $lastname = isset($params['lastname']) ? trim($params['lastname']) : '';
$salary = isset($params['salary']) ? trim($params['salary']) : '';
$hiredate= isset($params['hiredate']) ? trim($params['hiredate']) : '';

if($firstname!='')
{
    $name = '%'.$this->quote($firstname).'%';//quote is my own function
    $query->where("EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME LIKE '?'",$firstname); 
    }

if($lastname!='')
{
    $query->where("EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME =?",$lastname);
}

if($salary!='')
{
    $query->where("EMPLOYEES.SALARY=?",$salary);
}

if($hiredate!='')
{
    $query->where("EMPLOYEES.HIRE_DATE=?",$hiredate);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error comes from the fact that your calling `select()` against the controller object instead of the database object:

```
public function searchAction($params)
{
    //$this in this context is a Zend_Controller_Action object
    //you need to query against your database object.
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $query = $db->select()
                 ->from(
                array('EMPLOYEES'),
                array('FIRST_NAME','LAST_NAME','SALARY','HIREDATE')
                );
$query = $this->_makeParams($query,$params);
//again make sure to query against the database object
return $db->fetchAll($query);
}
```

if you don't have a database object created in your bootstrap.php or application.ini you can create one with the Zend_Db:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

Comment: I have done that in application.ini already by the following :resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "square"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

Comment: updated to reflect your use case. Add the $db variable as indicated to access the default database adapter. This assumes you only have one adapter setup.

Comment: My suggestion would be that you learn how to use models for interacting with your databases. Once you develop a model structure that works for you, you'll find it much easier to work with the DB and your controllers will be much simpler.

Comment: what does this error mean,,`Warning: Missing argument 1 for SearchController::searchAction(), called in /var/www/Employee/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php on line 516 and defined in /var/www/Employee/application/controllers/SearchController.php on line 251 `

Answer (score 1):

```
public function searchAction($params)
{
    $db      = Zend_Registry :: get('db');
    $select  = $db->select();
    $query = $select->from(
                array('EMPLOYEES'),
                array('FIRST_NAME','LAST_NAME','SALARY','HIREDATE')
                );
$query = $this->_makeParams($query,$params);
return $this->fetchAll($query);
}
```

You are getting the error because you have not created the object of Zend registry.So copy the function and replace your code

Comment: It's giving a message like :Message: No entry is registered for key 'db'